# how to get particular date with php

Tags: php, date

I want dates like current week dates from Monday to Wednesday and last week dates from last week Monday to last week Wednesday

I have tried this code

```
function last_to_last_week_date(){
    $previous_week = strtotime("-2 week +1 day");

    $start_week = strtotime("last monday",$previous_week);
    $end_week = strtotime("next sunday",$start_week);

    $start_week = date("Y-m-d",$start_week);
    $end_week = date("Y-m-d",$end_week);

    return $start_week.' '.$end_week ;
}
function last_week_date(){
    $previous_week = strtotime("-1 week +1 day");

    $start_week = strtotime("last monday",$previous_week);
    $end_week = strtotime("next sunday",$start_week);

    $start_week = date("Y-m-d",$start_week);
    $end_week = date("Y-m-d",$end_week);

    return $start_week.' '.$end_week ;
}
```

but with this, I have received last week dates and last to last week dates

can anybody help me with this

Comment: Are you up to iterating backwards in days to get your results? Not the most elegant solution, but it will work. As a concept, 1st find out the current dow (day of week). Then iterate backwards to Monday of the current week. For the second problem, iterate backwards to the previous monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply fix 2 rows in your code:

```
$end_week = strtotime("next wednesday",$start_week);  // <-- "next wednesday"
```

And for the current dates:

```
$previous_week = strtotime("+1 day");
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/S9Gc1)**

Output:

```
2020-01-20 2020-01-22
2020-01-27 2020-01-29
```

**DRY**

You can simplify your code. Use one method in each of two:

```
function optimDate($prev_w){

    $start_week = strtotime("last monday",$prev_w);
    $end_week = strtotime("next wednesday",$start_week);

    $start_week = date("Y-m-d",$start_week);
    $end_week = date("Y-m-d",$end_week);

    return $start_week.' '.$end_week ;
}
```

And these two method become like

```
function last_week_date(){ 
    return optimDate(strtotime("-1 week +1 day"));
}
function curr_week_date(){ 
    return optimDate(strtotime("+1 days"));
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/NUV1t)**

In fact, this also could be optimized.