# I have issue with getting particular date function with php

Tags: php

I want dates like if today is Tuesday then I want a date from starting of this week to the current day and get last week date from starting of last week to the current day like if today is `11-02-2020` and Tuesday then I want date like `10-02-2020 11-02-2020` and last week dates like `03-02-2020 04-02-2020`

for that, I have used below functions

```
function last_week_date(){
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    $day = date("l");
    $previous_week = strtotime("-1 week +1 day");

    $start_week = strtotime("last monday",$previous_week);
    $end_week = strtotime("next $day",$start_week);

    $start_week = date("Y-m-d",$start_week);
    $end_week = date("Y-m-d",$end_week);

    return $start_week.' '.$end_week ;
}
function this_week_date(){
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    $day = date("l");
    $previous_week = strtotime("+1 day");

    $start_week = strtotime("last monday",$previous_week);
    $end_week = strtotime("next $day",$start_week);

    $start_week = date("Y-m-d",$start_week);
    $end_week = date("Y-m-d",$end_week);

    return $start_week.' '.$end_week ;
}
```

but with this, I have received dates of the full week not till a particular day

can anybody help me with this

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59962041/how-to-get-particular-date-with-php)?

Comment: @Nick in that answer we give static days I want dynamic

Comment: So when you say start of week what do you mean? Monday?

Comment: @Nick yes correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will give you the results you want. You can simply pass it a parameter which is the number of weeks forward or backward to shift the dates to get this weeks/last weeks/next weeks days:

```
function week_date($weeks = 0) {
    $start = new DateTime("monday this week");
    $end = new DateTime();
    $start->modify("$weeks weeks");
    $end->modify("$weeks weeks");
    return $start->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $end->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

To call, use

```
echo week_date() . "\n";     // this week
echo week_date(-1) . "\n";   // last week
echo week_date(1) . "\n";    // next week
```

Output (as of Monday 2020-02-10):

```
2020-02-10 2020-02-10
2020-02-03 2020-02-03
2020-02-17 2020-02-17
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0lcP3)

Comment: you have put 3 echo function in that with which one we get current week  dates

Comment: @MNJ look at the comments on each `echo` statement

Comment: ohh sorry and Thank you :)